# Automate IE 11 download file popup : Java

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, download

Need to automate the download file popup in IE 11 without having the window focus. (I know we should not do, but need to do as a requirement).

Have tried
1. Robot (Requires window focus)
2. Sikuli (Requires window focus)
3. Actions (Doesnt work)

Can anyone suggest me some other way in which I can handle this? 
IE 11
Win 10

Need to click save and then cross button

[image]

Comment: IE has no API for the default download manager. whatever you can reverse engineer out of IE's internals may break when Microsoft releases an IE update. Maybe write a download manager instead?

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the update.. I think that will be my last resort for sure.